# NuxtJs element UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a Nuxt.js project, using Element UI to upload images, retrieving image URLs, and displaying them on the page, the initial display fails. However, it succeeds upon subsequent attempts using a delay timer. Any advice?
Displaying the list using the default Element components works fine; however, encountering this issue when customizing the array traversal for display

Comment: Perhaps you're *doing something wrong™* in your *code*?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check your browser's console in DevTools - it will show you the problem.